# IIS Rewrite rule to remove part of the url

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I'm having issues with css and js files being cached and a solution I found here was to add a querystring and version number to my links. Unfortunately this does not work with all browsers. Another solution proffered was to embed the version number into the filename and the remove it with URL rewrite.

My files are typically `http://Site/SiteScripts/Test_js.2018.2.11.6645.js` or

```
http://Site/Css/SiteCss.2018.2.11.6645.css
```

In both cases I need the 2018.2.11.6645 part removed. This is the Version that I get from Assembly and changes with each build but is always the format of yyyy.d+.d+.d+ where yyyy is current year and d+ is one or more digits. If it makes it easier I could just user the last 4 digits only e.g. `http://Site/SiteScripts/Test_js.6645.js`

The finished result should be http://Site/SiteScripts/Test_js.js and http://Site/Css/SiteCss.css

I've got the following regex that I think is a correct match for the filename and extension....

```
\w+\.\d+\.\d+.\d+\.\d+\.(js|css)
```

but I'm having trouble working out how to remove the version and the reconstructing the url to have the full path and filename plus extention without the version.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What language are you working with?  You could try `(.*)(?:.\d{4}\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(.*)`

Comment: @chrisz Thanks... this is a much better regex as it allows for any depth of directory structure. I can now reconstruct using {R:1}{R:2} and this give me the desired result. Please post as answer and I can mark. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`(.*)(?:.\d{4}\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/nrTTZz/2) and then use groups 1 and 2 to get your desired string.  Here is an example using javascript:

```js
var s = ['http://Site/SiteScripts/Test_js.2018.2.11.6645.js', 'http://Site/Css/SiteCss.2018.2.11.6645.css']

for (let i of s) {
  var re = /(.*)(?:.\d{4}\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(.*)/gm
  match = re.exec(i)
  console.log(match[1] + match[2])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace this regex:

```
\d{4}.\d\.\d{2}\.
```

With `""` to remove it, and [here is an example](https://regex101.com/r/9HVKTK/3).

The regex will match only the Version part of the URL.